# Why does this jQuery return an index of 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected">First Item</li>
    <li class="disabled">Second Item</li>
    <li class="separator">Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($("li:not(.disabled,.separator)").index());
```

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for index:

> the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first
>   element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Emphasis on `first element`.  But the above code returns `3`.  Based on the documentation shouldn't this code return `0`?

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9Vv/

**NOTE:**

My selector matches two elements: the first and last `LI`.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head. You have uncovered a regression. :)

Comment: Yay for me!!!  You can view the ticket here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10977

Comment: Based on my findings (see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8424662/50079)), I think the ticket is misleading. This is a regression introduced in 1.6.3 and should be reported as such. There is (of course) nothing in the 1.6.3 release notes indicating that the documented behavior of `index()` would have changed.

Comment: It definitely does not go into the detail that you do, but misleading?  My main point was to bring the discrepancy between documentation and functionality to someone's attention.  I'm not familiar with the release notes from 1.6.3 and wouldn't be comfortable restating your conclusion.  Could you possibly add it as a comment to the ticket?

Comment: See my answer for a potential fix. Here's a link to a fiddle containing a modified copy of the jQuery source, which alerts the correct answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9Vv/1/

Comment: Sure. Also read the answer of James Allardice, who was first to dissect the changeset. My point is that we have much richer and reliable information to offer than what the ticket states, so it would be a pity to let the jQuery people rediscover our findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** (see comments)
The original answer is incorrect... I'm going to keep it here for now so the comments make sense.

Looking at the jQuery source for `index`, you can see the [following snippet](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing.js#L141):

```
if ( !elem ) {
    return ( this[0] && this[0].parentNode ) ? this.prevAll().length : -1;
}
```

Compare this to the corresponding (if very different) snippet from an earlier release, 1.6.2. Note the use of `this[0]`:

```
return jQuery.inArray( this[0],
// If it receives a string, the selector is used
// If it receives nothing, the siblings are used
elem ? jQuery( elem ) : this.parent().children() );
```

It seems that in the current version the `this.prevAll` part causes the problem. If you change it to `this.eq(0).prevAll` (which replicates what the `index` documentation states) then you get the correct value returned. So it would appear this is a jQuery bug.

In the 1.6.2 version, `inArray` is used. That method returns the index of the first argument in the second argument (or `-1` if the first argument is not found in the second). As the first argument is `this[0]` (the first element in the matched set) we get the expected result.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9Vv/1/) with the modified jQuery source included. The correct result is alerted.

---

*Original answer (this is incorrect):*

Read the quoted part of the docs again carefully (bold highlighting added):

> the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first
>   element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**.

Just because two of the siblings have been removed from the matched set, it doesn't change the value returned by `index`. In other words, the matched element (`<li>Fourth Item</li>`) will always have index 3, relative to its siblings (unless, of course, new siblings are inserted into the DOM before the element in question).

Comment: But since the first and last `LI`s are matched should it select the first one (which has an index of 0)?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I'm going to look into it so I won't delete my answer just yet.

Comment: I was looking at the same right now, +1 for publishing the facts.

Answer (score 4):

It's probable that you found a discrepancy between actual jQuery functionality and what the docs say.

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) state

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.`

However, `.index()` is returning the index of the **last** element within the jQuery object.

This can be demonstrated (without introducing a potential issue with the :not selector) in your fiddle by `console.log( $("li").index() ); // 3`

Maybe a bug report on jQuery is needed?

Comment: **People, this is not a documentation issue. It's a regression.**

Comment: Was that directed at me? I did not say it was a documentation issue, but that it was a discrepancy between actual functionality and docs.

Comment: It was mainly directed at herd mentality upvoters, but it's applicable to you as well in the sense that the answer leaves the impression that this should be fixed by changing the documentation.

Comment: Maybe it leaves the impression with you. I never claimed it was a documentation issue in the first place. That's ultimately up to the jQuery team to verify.

Comment: Fair enough. But, since we have provided enough information here for anyone to reproduce the change in behavior, and since the 1.6.3 changelog is public knowledge, I 'll keep calling this a regression until someone produces arguments to the contrary.

Comment: Looks like this issue started back in `1.6.3` when they changed their approach to start using `.prevAll()` to count previous siblings. They need `.first().prevAll()` instead. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.3/src/traversing.js#L150-152

Comment: [Here's the change, and the unit test](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/9a96af1d59cc6a10b89b6f2489b04871a9c1c7fa#src/traversing.js). It only tests against a single element. This was back in June! ...I guess I should scroll down a bit first. This has been covered! :p

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Why not add this information to the jQuery ticket? That would certainly come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

**Confirmed, this is a regression introduced in jQuery 1.6.3. Earlier versions exhibit the expected behavior (return 0).**

After investigating, I have reluctantly come to the conclusion that this cannot be anything else other than a bug in jQuery.

Specifically, in this case at least, `index()` returns the index relative to its siblings of the second element matched (the bare `<li>`). This is despite the fact that

```
$("li:not(.disabled,.separator)").get(0)
```

correctly returns the `<li class="selected">`.

Furthermore, if we change the selector to

```
$("li:not(.disabled,.separator,:last-child)").index()
```

then `index` correctly returns 0.

**Tests done using jQuery 1.7.1**

Comment: Yes, after testing this is indeed a bug in jQuery. Good call.

Comment: @Alex: I 've tested and pinpointed 1.6.3 as the guilty release. Now let's find out what went wrong :)

Comment: @Jon - It appears what went wrong is a change from `this[0]` to `this` (amongst many other changes - the code is completely different in the latest version). See my (updated) answer.